# How to move/remove/join adjacent Blade Speed points in FCPX

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

So, the Blade Speed retiming tool in FCPX is half-awesome.

But once I have put a blade marker in I can't work out how to:

1. remove it (apart from immediate undo, i.e. later on)
2. move its position in relation to the src clip, i.e. I put the blade point in the wrong place, I want to move it without adjusting the retiming either side of the point
3. join adjacent retimed segments... related to above, if I put in a new blade point in the correct position I can't remove the wrong one (1) or see a way to join/merge the adjacent retiming segments

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer...

I still don't know how to remove a single blade speed point.  It is possible to remove *all* speed points for a clip by selecting the clip and choosing a new speed (eg Normal 100%) from the Retiming menu.

I still don't know how to join adjacent segments (kind of same thing as above).

Found out how to move the blade speed point relative to the clip itself without retiming:

1. double-click the blade speed centre handle and click the 'Edit' button

[image]

2. You get this icon you can drag in the timeline:

[image]

(classic bit of Apple "hidden UI" gotcha)

If you are zoomed in and you have a big speed differential either side of the centre point then it may not be at all obvious that you really are moving the src frame (fooled me before) because the preview changes are complex. But with Normal speed both sides it is clear this does what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

For #3 of your question, I could find some relevant info at [apple support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12549?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US).

To remove a through edit, do one of the following:

- Select either or both sides of the through edit point, and choose *Trim > Join Clips* (or press Delete).
- Select the clips on both sides of the through edit, and choose *Trim > Join Clips*.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently having a lot of trouble with rejoining retimed segments, but the solution that came to me seemed a little too obvious to actually be the recommended way of doing this.

It seems, however, that if you simply select a range that contains both retimed segments, and set a new speed for both of them, you can quickly "join" them, effectively removing the marking made when blading the speed originally.

That said, being able to quickly select more than one speed segments would make this much more practical if you had to do it often.